# Selenium grid: Logging on Hub

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

is there a way how to log node actions on Hub?

Imagine situation of "stress test" - I am having several nodes on several computers, all running against one Hub. Each of the node repeats cycle of actions, with intention to break the system.

Can I somehow send signal to the hub when the script crashes? For instance with statistics how many times did the script repeated before it crashed?

If yes, I am interested in Java pseudocode.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, have you thought about other options? e.g. Saving to a 'count' of somesort to a `.txt` file?

Comment: @JamieRees: I did not. Will count with it as "Plan B" because if you connect more than 20 computers to the grid, it starts beccoming quite excercise :)

Comment: Yes I understand that, Possibly if you are having that many connections you may want to store the data somewhere a bit better e.g. a database.